# No adapter attached; skipping layout No Solution Working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Before this post goes into negative i must tell None of previous Solution work for me

So,
I have a Fragment which has the recyclerview so i am initializing the recyclerview into `onCreateView` of my Code and I've Firebase Database as source of recyclerView data.
here is my Code:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        Product=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.P_Name);
        Tehsil=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.TehsilSearch);
        State=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.StateSearch);
        City=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.DistrictSearch);
        State.setOnItemSelectedListener(ss);
        Product.setOnItemSelectedListener(p);
        City.setOnItemSelectedListener(cc);
        rView=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.R_view);
        b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b.setOnClickListener(bclick);
        LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setAdapter(FBRA);
        return v;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener bclick=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatabaseReference mRef;
            mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads").child(ProductEntered).child(StateEntered).child(CityEntered).child(Tehsil.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),StateEntered+"\n"+CityEntered+"\n"+Tehsil.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RecyclerCropView> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecyclerCropView>().setQuery(mRef,RecyclerCropView.class).build();

            FBRA=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RecyclerCropView model) {

                    holder.setProductImage(model.getProfileImage());
                    holder.setProductImage(model.getProduct_Image());
                    holder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
                    holder.setQuantityUnit(model.getQuantityUnit());
                    holder.setName(model.getName());
                    holder.setMax(model.getMaximumPrice());

                    final String x=FBRA.getRef(position).getKey().toString();
                    holder.setDate(x);
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Itemclicked.class);
                            intent.putExtra("ProductName",ProductEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("State",StateEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("City",CityEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("tehsil",Tehsil.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("key",x);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclercard,parent,false);
                    return new ViewHolder(v);
                }
            };
            FBRA.notifyDataSetChanged();


          }

    };
```

please go through this also..

Comment: and what's your problem?

Comment: I am receiving a error No adapter attached;skipping layout 
And nothing is getting displayed over there in recycle view

Comment: Add this `FBRA.startListening();` before call setAdapter()

Comment: Were in function or in onCreateView

Comment: @MoHiTGuPtA Actually when you call setAdapter , at that time adapter is NULL.

Comment: So what do u suggest @Abhay koradiya

Comment: As @AbhayKoradiya said, when you are setting adapter it is NULL. So no matter if you initialise it later, RecyclerView will not have any effect. You should set adapter to RecyclerView when you create your adapter.

Comment: Mean in onclick

Comment: yes setadapter in onclick.

Comment: Its also not working tried it before

Comment: means after creating adapter object i.e after this- `FBRA=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder>(options) {`. In your button click

Comment: Its also not working

Comment: Check if you are using the right id of the RecyclerView to initialize the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by placing each recycler view attribute into onClick.
Means the setlayoutManager and .setAdapter together into onClick method of button